# how to create a pygtk status bar icon using quickly python

Tags: python, quickly, pygtk

How can i add an icon to the status bar using python ? like the skype icon ?

and is it possible to use the default notifications like those that appear when connecting or disconnecting to a wifi ?

Thank you

Comment: @Takkat: It is not a duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can i add an icon to the status bar using python ? like the skype
>   icon ?

It is called ['app indicator'](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/application-indicators/) not status bar icon, use the command

`quickly add indicator` for it

> and is it possible to use the default notifications like those that
>   appear when connecting or disconnecting to a wifi ?

[image]

It is [notify-osd](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/notification/),here is the [guide](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/notification/) for it

Comment: ^is it the output of 'quickly run'

Comment: Thank you :) if anyone had a problem with this in indicator.py line 20 change `AppIndicator3.Indicator` to `AppIndicator3.Indicator.new` and it will work

Comment: yes it was the output of `quickly run`

Comment: ^it is known bug in quickly.I forgot to comment solution. Any way congrats for finding answer yourself :)